# pgf math error, division by zero

Tags: pgfplots, errors

I have a valid `gnuplot` function (plots fine in `gnuplot`), with `pgfplots` fails to use:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\pgfplotsset{width=0.8\textwidth, height=0.6\textwidth}
\pgfplotsset{samples=200}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[mark=none, style=solid,
             enlargelimits=false, 
             xmin=0,xmax = 2.5,
             ymin=0,ymax = 2.5]
%
\addplot gnuplot{3*(x**(3-1))*exp(-x**3)};
%
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The error is

```
PGFPlots: reading {testplots.pgf-plot.table}
! Package pgfplots Warning: Axis range for axis y is approximately empty; enlarging it (it is [0.0:0.0])
! Package PGF Math Error: You've asked me to divide `231.00105000000000' by `0.0', but I cannot divide any number by `0.0'.
```

Comment: If you provide the key `domain=0:2.5` it works without any errors.

Comment: @percusse An answer?

Comment: @egreg Maybe but I still couldn't find why that particular number.

Comment: @percusse The default domain is `-5:5` and the value of the function at -5 is more than 10^56. I guess this has something to do with the weird error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quick fix is to stay away from the part that makes the data explode. Hence if you provide the key `domain=0:2.5` it works without any errors.

Initially I thought: *The problem comes from the fact that the default domain of plotting the functions is ( as egreg mentioned) [-5,5]. Since negative numbers make the exponential term explode,  (the first instance gives e^125 ).*

However it gets weirder which makes me think that this is not just an overflow problem. For example starting from -5, using `domain=-5:2` it gives the mentioned error but when this key is given as `domain=-2.4:2` up to `domain=-2.369:2` it gives this

```
\pgfplotsset{width=0.8\textwidth, height=0.6\textwidth}
\pgfplotsset{samples=200}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[no marks, style=solid,
             enlargelimits=false, 
             xmin=-5,xmax = 2.5,
             ymin=0,ymax = 5,domain=-2.369:2]
%
\addplot gnuplot{3*(x**(3-1))*exp(-x**3)};
%
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Notice how the `ymax` is violated. Also if I try to increase the `ymax` value, it gives me a `Dimension too large error`. Even weirder, it starts to give `Dimension too large` error when we go past -2.369 towards higher values. But if I remove the `ymax` option completely I get

[image]

So after seeing that I've removed the ymax and let the original code run and I get surprisingly.

[image]

I guess something is choked during the axis limit calculation. So it might be a bug or an internal limitation.

Comment: This is not really related to the problem at hand, but all those graphs hide the behavior of this function around `domain=0:2` (with `ymin=0`, `ymax=2`). Might be useful to show that graph, or at least point that out.

Comment: @PeterGrill Oops forgot to include my own comment to the question :) thanks.

Comment: Do you mean by your text that pgfplots has a possible bug?

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech Might be but I'm not sure. It might just be due to the huge numbers too.