# Tikz thinks I'm dividing by 0 when plotting Planck's Law

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to plot Planck's law using `tikz`. This works fine for the most part, but `tikz` thinks I'm dividing by `0` if I try to plot certain areas of the law. Here's a minimally working example of what I'm trying to do :

```
\documentclass[8pt,xcolor=dvipsnames,compress]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (4.2,0) node[right] {$\lambda$};
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {Flux};
    \draw[scale=3,domain=0.16:1,smooth,variable=\x,blue] plot ({\x},{((1/(exp(1/\x)-1)*(1/(\x^5)))/20});
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Now this works, but notice that my domain start at `0.16`. I'd like it to start earlier, at least around `0.1`, but if I start my domain at `0.1` I get a division by `0` error :

```
! Package PGF Math Error: You've asked me to divide `1' by `0.0', but I cannot divide any number by `0.0' (in '{((1/(exp(1/0.1)-1)*(1/(0.1^5)))/20}').
```

Any ideas as to what's causing this ?

Comment: You shouldn't divide by zero. The smallest amount possible is Planck's quantum ;-)

Comment: I don't get your error. Your code compiles fine with me.

Comment: Even when you change the domain to start at 0.1 ?

Comment: Mmh no. I'm afraid you can't do it though, this has come up before.  See also [pgf math error, division by zero](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/77790/4778)

Comment: Hmmm... So no real fix then ?

Comment: @ticster Well, whether this is a Tikz limitation or something else, I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Does it work when you remove `smooth` or `scale`? Which version of TikZ do you have? You can check it by putting `\pgfversion` some where on aframe

Comment: @percusse Removing those changes nothing. Version is 2.10.

Comment: Do you have any means to update? There are many things got fixed in terms of math library in version 3. Or you can try `pgfplots`. It handles math with more precision for plotting. And I think this is your problem as you miss the parenthesis http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41828/using-math-in-tikz

Comment: @percusse It's not on Synaptic, so I'm going to have to update it by hand. Going to try that and let you know how it works out.

Comment: Have a look at this one for vanilla installation http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to make sure that the `fpu` library is used so that arithmetic is does with floating point numbers.  The easiest way to do this is to use `pgfplots` ( built on top of `tikz`), which will do this by default.

In `pgfplots` the default style for axes are `boxed`, so some tweaking is needed to produce the style of plot you are after.  But the actual plotting command for the function is simple.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[8pt,xcolor=dvipsnames,compress]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel={\( \lambda \)},ylabel={Flux},
      axis x line=bottom,axis y line=left,
      every axis x label/.append style={at={(1,0)},right},
      every axis y label/.append style={at={(0,1)},above,rotate=-90}]
      \addplot[blue,domain=0.01:1,samples=200]
      {1/((exp(1/x)-1)*x^5*20)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe we should mention that TikZ v3 also works without any problems. So it is not solely the `fpu` library  requirement but due to a bug in v2.10.

Comment: @percusse I tried the posters original code with my `tikz.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.142)` and got overflow errors (rather than division by zero).  I await TL2015 to test newer versions.

Comment: Ah, yes my wrong wording. It goes back to the regular TeX behavior with TikZ v3 instead of divide by zero mistake.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I should point out for future readers that `\uncover` doesn't work properly when used around `\addplot` (and `\addplot<i-j>` doesn't work at all) so I had to use `\only`, and to make sure my plots didn't jump around drew a white (therefore invisible) plot that was the size of my plot with the biggest dimensions, therefore setting the axes to be the same throughout my slides.

Comment: Glad this helped.  Specifying common sizes for axes is a good way to get uniform plots.  `bemear` has the `overlayarea` environment to help with placement too.

Answer (score 6):

You have x<sup>5</sup> in the denominator with 0.1 as smallest value.
The precision of TeX's arithmetic via dimen registers in unit pt is only 2<sup>-16</sup> (= 1 sp). Therefore, 0.1<sup>5</sup> becomes 0.00001 and 0.00001 pt is smaller than 1 sp and the result is truncated to zero.

TikZ supports better arithmetics, e.g., via library `fpu`, see the other [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/248124/16967) of Andrew Swann. This example shows the use of library `fixedpointarithmetic`, which relies on package `fp`. The calculations take more time, but the result is more precise and the lower limit can be decreased to 0.025 before arithmetic overflow. I have also increased the number of samples to get a better curve shape.

```
\documentclass[8pt,xcolor=dvipsnames,compress]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fp}
\usetikzlibrary{fixedpointarithmetic}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (4.2,0) node[right] {$\lambda$};
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {Flux};
    \draw[
      samples=100,
      fixed point arithmetic,
      scale=3,domain=0.025:1,smooth,variable=\x,blue] plot
    ({\x},{((1/(exp(1/\x)-1)*(1/(\x^5)))/20});
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: `samples=100` cannot be used after `fixed point arithmetic` because of a bug in function `max`. I made a [bug report](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/360/).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, this does indeed take too long to calculate and given how often I compile my slides to check how they turn out, I'm going to go with the other answer. But thanks a lot for the details.